Understanding Kubernetes serviceaccounts and mounted secrets
I am new to Kubernetes and I am trying to understand some basic concepts such as serviceaccounts and secrets. As explained in the Kubernetes docs each pod associated with a serviceaccount has its secret mounted at /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token and the associated certificate is located is loacated at /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt to access the API-server.
How can I mimic that? I've tried the following:
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: sa
  namespace: sa
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: sa
  namespace: sa
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/service-account.name: sa
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token

and I am logging in into the container with:
⬢ [Docker] ❯ kubectl exec -it my-container --as system:serviceaccount:sa:sa -n spark -- /bin/sh
$ ls /var/run
lock  mount
$ ls /var/run/secrets
ls: cannot access '/var/run/secrets': No such file or directory
$ 

unfortunately I cannot find neighter the token nor the ca.crt.

Normally, when you create a ServiceAccount and associate it with a Pod, Kubernetes should automatically mount the service account token and certificate into the Pod at /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/.
You may have missed a step.
#!/bin/bash

# Variables
NAMESPACE="sa"
SERVICE_ACCOUNT="sa"
POD_NAME="my-pod"
IMAGE="nginx"  # Replace with your image if different

# Create the namespace
kubectl create namespace $NAMESPACE

# Create the service account
kubectl create serviceaccount $SERVICE_ACCOUNT -n $NAMESPACE

# Create a pod that uses the service account
cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: $POD_NAME
  namespace: $NAMESPACE
spec:
  serviceAccountName: $SERVICE_ACCOUNT
  containers:
  - name: my-container
    image: $IMAGE
    command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "sleep 3600"]
EOF

# Wait for the pod to be running
echo "Waiting for pod to be running..."
kubectl wait --for=condition=Ready pod/$POD_NAME -n $NAMESPACE --timeout=120s

# Verify the secrets are mounted
echo "Verifying the mounted secrets..."
kubectl exec -it $POD_NAME -n $NAMESPACE -- /bin/sh -c 'ls /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ && cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token && cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt'

echo "Script completed."

